# I can admin my database on XAMPP but I can't access it otherwise

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp

I can access phpMyAdmin and administrate my database.

I created a database "DB", a user "USR" with a password "PSWD" who only has access to "DB" and can only SELECT, INSERT and UPDATE.

But when I launch the shell through XAMPP and type

```
mysql --database=DB --user=USR --password=PSWD
```

I get an "access denied" error (and yes, I restarted the service).
Same thing happens when I try to access my database from my index.php script.

EDIT : Ok, I managed to pin point the cause of my problem, but it doesn't make any sense : It's the '%' wildcard in the host column that just doesn't work. If I put 'localhost' instead, then connecting from localhost works. The thing is, I actually NEED to access that database from anywhere... So what can I do ?

Comment: type 'mysql -u <username> -p' and enter you password.

Comment: Doesn't work... I still have "Access denied for user 'USR'@'localhost' (using password : YES).

The user table in the mysql database has my user USR, and the password is there too (encrypted, of course).

But it still doesn't work... I don't understand.

Comment: Did you try the root account?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
mysql -u root
```

if it works, check user's Hosts

```
USE mysql;
SELECT User, Host FROM user;
```

It should look like

```
+--------------+-----------+
|     User     |    Host   |
+--------------+-----------+
| yourusername | localhost |
+--------------+-----------+
| yourusername | 127.0.0.1 |
+--------------+-----------+
```

If you dont have `localhost` you need to add a record with it.

[image]

If connecting to Mysql with root and no password did not work, please try,

```
mysql -u your_username -p password -h 127.0.0.1
```

And check user's Hosts (explained in previous steps)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following: `mysql --user=USR -p`

Once you press enter, you will be prompted for password. Enter it and you can switch to database using: `use db;`

Comment: Doesn't work... I still have "Access denied for user 'USR'@'localhost' (using password : YES)

Comment: Ah, ok. Your localhost works right? And you need to be able to access it remotely? By default, MySQL allows remote connections. How are you trying to use it? Can you provide code/command?